# Installed fonts not detected by HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts

I am writing some text on the HTML5 Canvas using JavaScript. I am using two variatoions of "Lato" font to write some text. The font has 8 different variations including light, bold, italic, bold-italic, normal etc. The problem is that writing text on canvas using:

```
context.font = 'bold 16px "Lato"';
```

But using `bold` makes the Canvas write with a generic font instead of Lato. The font works properly once I remove the `bold` part. What could cause this issue?

I am not loading the font. It is already installed on the system. I tried it with other fonts but they work properly on using the `bold` keyword.

Comment: The font is installed on your system, or are you importing it into the page? If so, how? Is it two variations of the same font, or two different fonts where one of them is named "... bold"? Does this happen with other fonts as well?

Comment: Are you sure the font is actually loaded before the code that draws the text is executed?

Comment: @Pekka웃 No, it doesn't happen with other fonts. I have not tried all the fonts but it did not happen with other two fonts that I am using. :)

Comment: OK. Is the font installed on your system, or are you importing it into the page? If so, how? Is it two variations of the same font, or two different fonts where one of them is named "...bold"?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The font is installed on the system. In the installed fonts directory, it says "Lato Bold", "Lato Light", "Lato Italic" etc.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I just tried to use `context.font = '16px "Lato Bold"'` but the text was still written in a generic font.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's wrong. I would try `LatoBold`

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks but that did not work either. I tried it with may other fonts like `Raleway`, `Roboto`, `Russo One` etc. `Lato` seems to be the only font having issues at this point.

Comment: It's likely the way the font exposes itself to the system. Depending on your OS you might be able to inspect the font and see whether there is a specific way to write out the font name,

Comment: @Pekka웃 You are right. It is working now. I double clicked on the font and copied the name that appeared in the new window. :)